# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method (actualizando Vagrant y Homestead)

Tags: laravel, composer, vagrant

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel, en local lo trabajo con homestead 11.2, vagrant 2.2.14 y php 7.3, me llegó notificación de una nueva versión de vagrant, la 2.2.16, hice la actualización y comencé a recibir el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit33193568e160e47b43978a9cc28985b4::getLoader() in /home/vagrant/code/app-amparo/vendor/autoload.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/app-amparo/public/index.php(24): require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/code/app-amparo/vendor/autoload.php on line 7

Probé con `composer update` y el error se mantiene.

Probé borrando el directorio vendor y corriendo `composer install` pero el error continúa.

Probé desinstalando la versión 2.2.16 y volviendo a la 2.2.14 pero el error no se va, les agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Update: Hago un `vagrant destroy` para eliminar la estructura, vuelvo a ejecutar `vagrant up` y levanta todo bien, luego hago `php artisan migrate --seed` y `php artisan config:cache` sin problemas, al acceder a la web (en mi caso app-amparo.test) la primera vez lo hace bien, pero algo se genera con el primer acceso que al intentar seguir navegando se produce el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, recientemente había actualizado Homestead también a la versión 11.2.0 (hoy es la última) pero no me había dado problemas, cuando actualizo vagrant desde 2.2.14 a 2.2.16 empezó el problema.

Y terminó funcionando volviendo atrás con las versiones de ambos, instalé Homestead 11.1.0 y Vagrant 2.2.14, o sea que algún bug no resuelto hay en las nuevas versiones. Espero le sirva a alguien más.